# Convert DateTime without time zone to UTC

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, utc

I've got a problem converting DateTime string values into UTC. The customer will upload an file with DateTime values in 15min steps ( one file include the whole day ):

```
Date (MET)         Value
25.10.2015 00:00   2       [DST - Germay offset +2]
25.10.2015 00:15   2       [DST]
25.10.2015 00:30   2       [DST]
25.10.2015 00:45   2       [DST]
...                ...
25.10.2015 02:00   2       [DST]
25.10.2015 02:15   2       [DST]
25.10.2015 02:30   2       [DST]
25.10.2015 02:45   2       [DST]
25.10.2015 02:00   2       [Winter time - Germany offset +1]
25.10.2015 02:15   2       [Winter time]
25.10.2015 02:30   2       [...]
25.10.2015 02:45   2
25.10.2015 03:00   2
...                ...
```

There is no DateTime offset inside the file. **[DST]** and **[Winter time]** is just for visualization ( its not included inside file! ). Is there any way to convert a given DateTime string into UTC without knowing the offset?

What I expect:

```
Date (UTC)         Value
25.10.2015 22:00   2       [DST: 25.10.2015 00:00 +2]
25.10.2015 22:15   2       [DST: 25.10.2015 00:15 +2]
25.10.2015 22:30   2       [DST: 25.10.2015 00:30 +2]
25.10.2015 22:45   2       [DST: 25.10.2015 00:45 +2]
...                ...
25.10.2015 00:00   2       [DST: 25.10.2015 02:00 +2]
25.10.2015 00:15   2       [DST: 25.10.2015 02:15 +2]
25.10.2015 00:30   2       [DST: 25.10.2015 02:30 +2]
25.10.2015 00:45   2       [DST: 25.10.2015 02:45 +2]
25.10.2015 01:00   2       [Winter time: 25.10.2015 02:00 +1]
25.10.2015 01:15   2       [Winter time: 25.10.2015 02:15 +1]
25.10.2015 01:30   2       [...]
25.10.2015 01:45   2
25.10.2015 02:00   2
...                ...
```

I have to store these DateTime values in a MySQL datebase table.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll have to know the customer's time zone ID, such as `"Europe/Berlin"` in the case of Germany.  If you don't know the time zone at all, then you cannot do this.  Still, there may be ambiguity during the "fall-back" DST transitions.  If you have enough data, you might be able to resolve the ambiguity based on the order the rows appear in the file (assuming they are intended to be sequential).

Comment: As far as implementation goes, you can do everything you asked with the PHP `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` classes.  If you search, you'll find many examples of that.  If you are not getting it working, then edit your question to show the code you have tried.